# How to open network share subfolders from command prompt?

Tags: java, windows, macos, networking

I have a network share `\\host-IP\folder\subFolder`. I want to open this from java where username and password should be prompted in connect to window. I wanted to achieve this in both MAC and windows. Any help ?

EDIT

IN windows :
using `explorer` command i could acheive upto the root of the shared path. If i give sub folders it says `the path does not exists`. But if i try the same from run window (windows+R) it works (it prompts for the username and password). But i do not know how to call the same from java.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this thread.

[Write I/O file to shared network drive using credentials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10599999/write-i-o-file-to-shared-network-drive-using-credentials)

Providing that you write the UI that prompts the user to enter authentication credentials yourself, it should be possible to access the share using the [CIFS library](http://jcifs.samba.org/). However, do make sure to take a look at my comment about having the OS take care of the authentication to the network share transparently to your application.

Edit: Using CIFS you should of course write the network path samba style, i.e. smb://host-IP/folder/subFolder

Comment: I want the windows OS to prompt for connect to window. If i use `Runtime.getRuntime.exec("explorer \\\\host-IP\\folder")` it prompts for username and password. If i use `Runtime.getRuntime.exec("explorer \\\\host-IP\\folder\\subfolder")` it says the error `network path does not exist`.

Answer (score 0):

This may help you

```
 Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
 Process pr = rt.exec("explorer "+"\\\\"+"<SERVER>"+"\\"+"<FOLDER>"+"\\"+"<SUB FOLDER>");
```

Comment: no luck with this. Please see my comment for dkateros answer.

Comment: @Samrat can you post your command and error please!! In my case it works fine

Comment: when i run ` Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
   Process pr = rt.exec("explorer "+"\\\\"+"xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"+"\\"+"Folder"); ` without sub folder it prompts me for username and password and if i run with subfolder `  Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
   Process pr = rt.exec("explorer "+"\\\\"+"xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"+"\\"+"Folder"+"\\"+"SUB");` it says the path does not exist or is not a directory.

Comment: Check weather its working in dos or not, open cmd and put this command

Comment: In dos it is not working. But if i try the same from start-run without explorer by providing network folder upto sub `\\xx.xx.xx.xx\folder\sub` it prompts for the username and password

Comment: enter those username and password, and check it remember. Then try the command

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20932/discussion-between-samrat-and-shantanu-banerjee)