# How to authenticate and connect to the network drive in java

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jcifs

Could any one please tell how to authenticate and connect to the network drive(folder) in java in windows system. We tried with following code to connect to the network drive.

```
Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /C START  net use M: \\127.0.0.1\\sharedNetworkDrive");
```

But problem with this code is not having any authentication(username and password) for that shared drive (sharedNetworkDrive). Can anyone please guide how to do this.

Comment: use `lib` mentioned in this post (http://stackoverflow.com/a/10600116/2749470)