# read file from remote pc where directory contain user name and password authentication

Tags: java

I can to write a text file from remote pc which contain a share folder without any authentication. But when I try to read file from a share folder with authentication it cannot read the file.the actual file location is

```
url : 10.11.201.45
Drive : D
username :BELY
password : BELY-du
file location : D://Share_BELY/bb/txt.
```

Here's my code:

```
    // The name of the file to open.
    String fileName = "//10.11.201.45/D$/Share-BELY/BELY:BELY-du@/bb.txt";

    String line = null;
    try {
        // FileReader reads text files in the default encoding.
        FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(fileName);
        // Always wrap FileReader in BufferedReader.
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
        while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }    
        // Always close files.
        bufferedReader.close();            
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException ex) {
        System.out.println("Unable to open file '" + fileName + "'");                
    }
    catch(IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("Error reading file '" + fileName + "'");                   
        // Or we could just do this: 
        // ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [JCIFS](https://jcifs.samba.org/) library we can achieve that.

**Sample Code :**

```
        NtlmPasswordAuthentication auth = new NtlmPasswordAuthentication("domain", "username", "password");
        SmbFile smbFile = new SmbFile("//path", auth);
        InputStream in;
        if (smbFile.exists()) {
            in = smbFile.getInputStream();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Various solutions using different libraries

[Write I/O file to shared network drive using credentials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10599999/write-i-o-file-to-shared-network-drive-using-credentials)

or

[Read remote file in java which needs username and password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11724576/read-remote-file-in-java-which-needs-username-and-password)

or

http://sanjaal.com/java/875/java-utilities/java-tutorial-using-jcifs-to-copy-files-to-shared-network-drive-using-username-and-password/