# Android : Read Remote Location Folder Name and file Name

Tags: android, directory, subdirectory, file-access

I am connected to a Server whose address is 192.168.1.254 and on typing this address in the browser it is showing the list of available folder [image]
i want to display the name of the folder in my android application i have tried the following code but no-luck.

```
try {
        SmbFile test = new SmbFile("smb://192.168.1.254");
        SmbFile[] files = test.listFiles();
        if (files != null)
            for (SmbFile s : files) {
                Log.d("debug", s.getName());
            }
    } catch (SmbException e) {
        Log.d("debug", "ERROR");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("debug", "ERROR");
    }
```

which i find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29745954)
and i also tried

```
File f = new File("//192.168.1.254");
//also tried with File f = new File("http//192.168.1.254");
File[] files = f.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {
public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
    // Specify the extentions of files to be included.
    return name.endsWith(".bmp") || name.endsWith(".gif");
}
});

 // get names of the files
String[] fileNamesArray = null; 
for (int indx = 0; indx < files.length(); indx++) {
Log.d("name",files[indx].getName());
}

return fileNamesArray;
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems you need FTP client for list files on remote location. Try to use, for example, [ftp4j](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ftp4j/files/ftp4j/1.7.2/ftp4j-1.7.2.zip/download) library as described in it's [official documentation](http://www.sauronsoftware.it/projects/ftp4j/manual.php) or [this Android Example](http://snowdev.red5apps.com/index.php/android-ftp-example) by devert. Exactly list files on remote FTP server with ftp4j by [Arun](http://techdive.in/users/arun) you can find [here](http://techdive.in/java/ftp4j-list-files-remote-ftp-server):

> ```
>     FTPClient client = null;
>     try {       // Get the FTP Connection from the
>         Utility class client =FTPUtility.connect(ipAddress, userName,
>                 password);
>         if (client != null) {           /* List all file inside the directory */
>             FTPFile[] fileArray = client.list();
>             System.out.println("List of files...");
>             for (int i = 0; i < fileArray.length; i++) {
>                 FTPFile file = fileArray[i];
>                 if (file != null) {
>                     if (file.TYPE_FILE == FTPFile.TYPE_FILE) // File                    {
>                         System.out.println("File Name = " + file.getName() + " ; File Size = " + file.getSize() + " ;Modified Date = " + file.getModifiedDate());
>                 } else if (file.TYPE_DIRECTORY == FTPFile.TYPE_DIRECTORY) // Directory
>                 {
>                     System.out.println("Directory Name = " + file.getName() + " ; Directory Size = " + file.getSize() + " ;Modified Date = " + file.getModifiedDate());
>                 } else if (file.TYPE_LINK == FTPFile.TYPE_LINK) // Link
>                 {
>                     System.out.println("Link Name = " + file.getName() + " ;Modified Date = "
>                             + file.getModifiedDate());
>                 }
>             }
>         }
>     }
> }   catch(
> Exception e)
>
> {
>     System.err.println("ERROR : Error in Connecting to Remote Machine... Hence exitting...");       //
>     e.printStackTrace();
>     System.exit(2);
> }
>
> finally
>
> {
>     try {
>         client.disconnect(true);
>     } catch
>             (Exception e) {
>     }
> }
> ```

**Update**

If "there is no active port for ftp , and my current finding is device is having only 4 active port i.e 80,443,3333,8192" seems file list send over HTTP and you can download it via [`HttpURLConnection`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection) and parse response. Something like this:

```
HttpURLConnection connection = null;
BufferedReader reader = null;

try {
    URL url = new URL("http://192.168.1.254");

    connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
    connection.connect();

    int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();

    InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();

    reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
    StringBuilder responseStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    String line = "";

    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        responseStringBuilder .append(line);
        responseStringBuilder .append("\n");
    }

    // Parse responseStringBuilder.toString() (probably as HTML) here:
    ... 

} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    if (connection != null) {
        connection.disconnect();
    }
    try {
        if (reader != null) {
            reader.close();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: i have tried (not programmatically but using filezilla )this earlier but found that there is no Active port for ftp , and my current finding is device is having only 4 active port i.e 80,443,3333,8192

Comment: @ShubhamJain Please see update about `HttpURLConnection`.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to download html as a string from the server. Then use

```
 urlConnection = new URL("your_url").openConnection();
 reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));

 while ((String line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            stringBuilder.append(line).append("\n");
        }
 String your_data = Html.fromHtml(stringBuilder.toString());
```

This will contain the table in text format. You can process it to get the required data.