# Java programming check if network file exists

Tags: java, network-programming, smb

I need to search for file in the network and check if the file exist or not, I use this code:

```
File listOfFiles = new File ("\\\\server\\share\\TEST\\file.xml");
if (listOfFiles.exists() && listOfFiles.isFile()){
   // ...
}
```

but it seems that the user didn't have permission to access the network driver. I need to send the user name and password for the user who have rights to this driver, but I don't know how.

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/a/10600116/1469259

Comment: related http://superuser.com/questions/344775/passing-unc-username-and-password-within-a-unc-path - you can instead mount the share to a drive letter and then access it like a regular file. Credentials are then handled by the mount

Comment: the problem is I can't import NtlmPasswordAuthentication, as I said I use java in Eclipse.  and share a drive conn't help because the issue is that the user who run the application is a local user and didn't have a permission to access the other driver in the network