# Create a directory and save file in a network location from Servlet

Tags: java, file, tomcat, servlets, filesystemexception

I have deployed a *webApplication* in a `Tomcat Server` (v8), which runs a service in a `Windows 2008 R2` PC. In this *webApplication*, the user uses a form to upload files (photos). What I want is to store these photos in a `NAS` disk in my network (both server and NAS disk is under the same network).

I read and followed this relevant [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18664715/2594961). I tried firstly to save the photos in the local disk of my server `C:`and it worked!

```
public void saveFiles(List<Part> fileParts,String targetId) { 
        String pathRoot = "C:\\Share\\photos\\;
        String date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());

        try {
            int counter = 1;
            for (Part filePart : fileParts) {

                String destPath = pathRoot + "\\" + targetId;    
                Boolean flag = new File(destPath).mkdirs();                   
                System.err.println("mkdirs flag = " + flag);

                File file = new File(destPath, targetId + " " + date + "-" + counter + ".jpg");

                try (InputStream input = filePart.getInputStream()) {
                    Files.copy(input, file.toPath());
                }

                counter++;
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

However, if I change the location path to `NAS` disk

```
String pathRoot = "\\\\192.168.0.7\\Share\\photos\\";
```

then I get the following error:

```
java.nio.file.FileSystemException: \\192.168.0.7\Share\photos\machines\4 20180704110827-1.jpg: Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password.
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.newByteChannel(Unknown Source)
    at java.nio.file.spi.FileSystemProvider.newOutputStream(Unknown Source)
    at java.nio.file.Files.newOutputStream(Unknown Source)
    at java.nio.file.Files.copy(Unknown Source)
    at com.yaylitizis.production.Actions.saveFiles(Actions.java:1797)
    at com.yaylitizis.production.Actions.processRequest(Actions.java:510)
    at com.yaylitizis.production.Actions.doPost(Actions.java:1893)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.yaylitizis.production.FilterUTF8.doFilter(FilterUTF8.java:27)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:673)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1526)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1482)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

In order to avoid the above error, how I can add the credentials of the network disk?

**Edit 1**

I mapped the network disk from Windows and the folder is accessible. However, the error still exists..

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this in 2 ways:

1) Since the "login" in network drive is done by windows, go on your server (where tomcat is installed and running), access the shared folder `\\192.168.0.7\Share\photos`, and when it asks for credentials, put them and save with the checkbox *remember credentials* on Windows. You can then edit or remove from *Manage your network password* on control panel. Look [here](http://www.pctips3000.com/how-to-manage-stored-credentials-in-windows-server-2008/) for more info

2) You have to use external libraries for Java. There's an helpful answer about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10600116/1984767)

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Runtime.exec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html) to execute `net use \\192.168.0.7\Share\photos your-password /user:your-domain\your-user-name /persistent:yes /savecred`. Only need to do it once during the initialization of your Web application.

Comment: It doesn't work.. Now I get an error `java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException`

Comment: Well, where is the error thrown? Did you get the path right? `NoSuchFile` is different from authentication related errors...